# Error in optim(par = par, fn = fun, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lb, upper = ub) : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to optimize the function "fun" for the weights (w_opt) but I get the following error:

```
Error in optim(par = par, fn = fun, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lb, upper = ub) : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
This is My code:

```
# matrix of 6 vectors of size 500x6
dens_fore <- cbind(garch_1, garch_2, garch_3, gjr_1, gjr_2, gjr_3)

w_eq -> 1/6
n_spec -> 6
par <-  rep(w_eq, n_spec)
lb <- rep(0, n_spec)

# Objective function
fun <- function(w_opt, dat = dens_fore){
  w_1 <- w_opt[1]
  w_2 <- w_opt[2]
  w_3 <- w_opt[3]
  w_4 <- w_opt[4]
  w_5 <- w_opt[5]
  w_6 <- w_opt[6]
  cumsum(log(sum(dat[,1]*w_1, dat[,2]*w_2, dat[,3]*w_3, 
                 dat[,4]*w_4, dat[,5]*w_5, dat[,6]*w_6)))
}

optim_fun <- optim(par = par,
                   fn = fun, 
                   method = "L-BFGS-B",
                   lower = lb, 
                   upper = Inf)
```

PS : I need to find 500 sets of optimal weights for all 500 lines of the dens_fore matrix (this matrix has no infinite values)

Comment: Try changing your argument names so that they don't match your expected variable names. For instance, try changing `dens_fore = dens_fore` to `dat = dens_fore` (and updating internal references).

Comment: When I do that I get the following new error:  Error in optim(par = par, fn = fun, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lb, upper = Inf) : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Comment: The "promise" error is due to how R parses function arguments with default values. `function(x, y=x)` says that if the user does not supply `y`, then look at the closest definition of `x`. In this case, it is in the function declaration itself. In your case, it found `dens_fore` within the function declaration, so was trying to use it ... but it had not been defined yet, it was still "unrealized" in a sense by R, as a "promise for a value later to be found". (Frankly, 'promises' in programming languages are a bit advanced to describe in detail here ... and I'm no guru there)

Comment: I suggest you shift your question from "promise" to this new one, including [edit]ing the question body, updating your function to the current changed form. It is difficult to troubleshoot that error without sample data, though, since that's a mathematical problem that can best be troubleshot with your data. Sample data is likely not going to cut it, but only you can know that :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand it better now. Do you have any idea about the new error I get? I tried to change the inf of the upper bound to a vector of numbers but the error remains. Also, the dens_fore matrix has no infinite values.

Comment: Not without sample data. Try one of the many other questions on SO that share that error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+L-BFGS-B%20needs%20finite%20values%20of%20%27fn%27